# python google appengine db.Model add a parent after instance has been constructed

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have some models in my datastore and I wanted to add in a parent relationship as described by the parent keyword in the constructor on this page:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html

Is this possible and if so, what would be the cleanest way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't; the parent's key path is part of the entity's key, which can't be changed after the entity is in the datastore. You'll need to create a new entity with the same data and the new parent and delete the original entity.

Answer (score -2):

Your parent class:

```
class Parent(db.Model):
```

Your child class:

```
class Child(Parent):
```

*edit*

If you're looking to update existing data then Wooble is correct.

Comment: This is wrong in any case - parent relationships are created using the `parent` argument to the constructor, not via inheritance.